# What is the correct translation of "Serviamus in veritate"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, motto

Please translate "Serviamus in veritate". I think it means *We serve the truth*, but some say that it means *We serve in truth*.

This is a motto that I'd like to have translated. Thanks, in advance

Comment: Thank you all so much for taking the time to reply. You have inspired me to start learning Latin.

Answer (score 5):

The word *serviamus* is in the subjunctive, rather than the indicative. If it were in the indicative it would mean *we serve*, but in the subjunctive, it means *may we serve…*, or *let us serve…*.

The prepositional phrase *in vertitate* means *in truth*. In order for it to mean, "May we serve the truth…", it would have to be in the dative (*veritati*) without a preposition.

Therefore, it might be translated as:

> May we serve in truth.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Expedito's answer: "In truth" sounds a bit strange in modern English, but this motto is presumably an allusion to John 4:23, in the Latin (Vulgate) translation: veri adoratores adorabunt Patrem in spiritu et veritate (KJV: the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth).

Answer (score 3):

Googling this motto brings one to the site of [this secondary school](https://www.mercytuam.com/mission-and-aims/) in Galway, Ireland, where it says:

> Our Crest declares that we serve God in truth”Serviamus in veritate”

Looks like rather than translating literally they chose to paraphrase.